# SSSD For Authentication & SAMBA For File Sharing

Tags: samba, sssd

As an alternative to winbindd, I have setup SSSD on a machine so that it can authenticate AD domain accounts, which is working great. However, this same machine also needs to act as a file server, so I believe I need to have SAMBA running (with winbindd not running).

The clients which need to access the file share are not joined to the domain, however I want the clients to authenticate with the server using AD credentials.

Is it possible to have a server which is joined to a domain with SSSD and sharing files using SAMBA, also have clients that are not joined to the domain access said shares using AD credentials?

/etc/samba/smb.conf

```
    [global]
       workgroup = DOMAIN
       kerberos method = secrets and keytab
       log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
       log level = 3
       passdb backend = ldapsam:"ldap://domain.net"
       realm = DOMAIN.NET

    [files]
       guest ok = yes
       path = /srv/files
       read only = no
```

I am attempting to mount the share from the client using the following command:

```
mount.cifs //192.168.1.101/files /mnt/ -o user=user,pass=password,domain=domain.net
```

Here is a cleaned up log of the access attempt from the server side:

```
get_dc_list: preferred server list: "ad.domain.net, ad.domain.net"
Connecting to 192.168.1.100 at port 445

check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user [domain.net]\    [user]@[] with the new password interface
check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [computername]\[user]@[]
check_sam_security: Couldn't find user 'user' in passdb.
check_winbind_security: Not using winbind, requested domain [computername] was for this SAM.
check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [tevans] -> [tevans] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER

NT error packet at ../source3/smbd/sesssetup.c(267) cmd=115 (SMBsesssetupX) NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
Server exit (failed to receive smb request)
```